# Prevent Jsoup Element object tags lowercase

Tags: xml, parsing, soap, jsoup, lowercase

I am korean.

I don`t speak english very well.

I like Jsoup.

I need XML(soap) parse in my project.

I understand Parser.xmlParser() of Document object.

But when I use Element object change lowercase character.

ex)
`Element element = new Element("TEST") -> <test></test>`

So, I checked these solution.

[First]

`Document document = Jsoup.parse("<soapenv:Envelope.....", "", Parser.xmlParse())`

`Node node = new Element("TEST")`

`Element element = (Element)node; -> <TEST>/<TEST>`

`document.getElementByTag("soapenv:Body").get(0).appendChild(element)`

[Second]

`Document document = Jsoup.parse("", "", Parser.xmlParse())`

`Element element = document.appendElement("TEST")`

blah~blah~

Is any problem?

I hope Element object "new XMLElement("TEST")" or "new HTMLElement("test")" like "new HashMap, new LinkedHashMap" Interface format....

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having by calling `new Element(tagname)` is that there is no document context passed to creator that you want the tag to be case sensitive, so jsoup is defaulting to it's lowercase (HTML) behavior.

Here's a couple example ways to make sure that the case sensitive settings are applied to the new elements:

```java
Document document = Jsoup.parse("<soapenv:Envelope>Foo</soapenv:Envelop>", 
    "", Parser.xmlParser());
document.append("<TEST id=1>Bar</TEST>");

Element second = document.createElement("Test");
document.appendChild(second);

System.out.println(document.outerHtml());
```

Giving:

```html
<soapenv:Envelope>Foo</soapenv:Envelope><TEST id="1">Bar</TEST><Test></Test>
```

For more info, see [Document#createElement(tagname)](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.html#createElement(java.lang.String)) and [Element#append(html)](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#append(java.lang.String))